# How to visualize output of JUnit integration tests in IntelliJ when using docker-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, integration-testing

IntelliJ has a nice integration with JUnit that allows me to run some or all of my unit tests and visualize the results of each test and test class with a collapsible/expandable hierarchy that even takes into account JUnit5 nested test classes. I can click on any failed test to see the log output from running just that method.  It looks like this:

[image: intelliJ JUnit test runner]

I have now defined an integration test phase to my project using two popular Maven plugins:

- `maven-failsafe-plugin` separates my JUnit tests into two phases.  The test classes ending in "Test" run during the *test* phase, and those ending in "IT" run during the *integration-test* phase.
- fabric8's `docker-maven-plugin` which I'm using to spin up a test database in the *pre-integration-test* phase and shut it down in the *post-integration-test* phase.

I can tell IntelliJ to run a Maven command (such as `maven clean verify`) that runs this lifecycle and tells me if the tests have passed.  However, a Maven "run configuration" in IntelliJ doesn't produce the same helpful output.  All I get is the success or failure status of each phase, and I can navigate to the console output for a phase, but not an individual test.  The output looks like this:

[image: IntelliJ maven runner]

So here's my question: **Is there any way to configure IntelliJ (or Maven, or both) to give that hierarchical test-by-test output while keeping the Maven lifecycle I've defined, with the temporary use of a docker-container database for my integration tests?**

I know that I can *manually* spin up the test database container, use IntelliJ's JUnit runner for my integration tests, and then *manually* stop the container.  Can I do better?

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a deep look into https://www.testcontainers.org so you can write your tests within JUnit Jupiter and have the same things inside IDEA and have the same integration in your IDE and you get rid of docker-maven-plugin....you can use `*IT.java` to name those integration tests and run them during the integration-test phase...

Comment: @khmarbaise I looked at TestContainers and decided against it, because I want to be able to run the tests not only against a test container but also against the real database (or a replica of it).  I intend to use Spring profiles or Maven profiles to determine which is used.  With TestContainers I'd have to maintain two different versions of each test's code.

Comment: For the tests to run against a real database which I think is the wrong way cause Tests have defined setup etc. a real database does not...which can be solved by using simply a different profile/configuration...and if you have to have to different versions of test code I think you are doing your tests wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no tool to show test-by-test output while keeping the Maven lifecycle as Maven run configuration is used in this case. Please use Junit run configuration for Class/method output in test runner tab.